# Vuejs - Trying to get the updated store.state data in my router

Tags: vue.js

I’m trying to get the `store.state.role` data in my router to determine which routes file it should use for the routes.

When i `console.log(store.state)` i see that the `store.state.role` has the correct data i need. But when i target the parameter like `console.log(store.state.role)` it shows the default value from my store which isn't the same as what i see when i `console.log(store.state)`.

this is my store file

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: 
    {
        //User      
        login_state: false,
        refreshUser: false,
        role: '',
        target: '',

        currentProject: '',
    },
    mutations: 
    {
        //Update user token
        updateUserToken(state, payload)
        {
            localStorage.setItem('token', payload);
            state.login_state = true;
        },

        //Update role
        updateRole(state, payload)
        {
            state.role = payload;
        },

        //Login state switch
        loginStateUpdate(state, payload)
        {
            state.login_state = payload;
        },

        //Refresh userdata
        userRefresh(state)
        {
            state.refreshUser = !state.refreshUser
        },

        updateProject(state, payload)
        {
            state.currentProject = payload
        }

    },
    getters: 
    {

    },
    actions: 
    {

    },
    modules: 
    {

    }
})
```

this is my router file

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import Tenant from "./tenant";
import Tenancy from "./tenancy";
import {tenancy} from '../resources/api.config'
import {Http} from '@/util/http'
import store from '../store'

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const host = window.location.host.toLowerCase().split(".")[0];

let routes;

if (host != tenancy.toLowerCase()) 
{
  console.log(store.state.role) //Returns '' while it's 'admin'
  routes = Tenant;
  store.commit('updateTarget', 'tenant'); 
}
else 
{
  console.log(store.state.role) //Returns '' while it's 'admin'
  routes = Tenancy;
  store.commit('updateTarget', 'tenancy');
}

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
});
export default router;
```

Why is this happening and how can i get the data i need ?

Comment: Did you import Vuex and the store before the router? And where exactly do you call console.log?

Comment: @FloWy updated my question with the code. I do import the store.

Comment: This is most likely a timing problem. I assume you have another file that populates the store with the user's role--that most likely hasn't happened by the time this file is executing.

Comment: @JasonSmith Yes the store.state.role is updated from the loginComponent. The thing that confuses me is that when i console.log(store.state) it does show the updated role but when i console.log(store.state.role) it doesn't.

Comment: You should avoid changing the store data directly, use mutations instead. Only the mutations should change the state. Doing otherwise will make it hard to properly debug your app, will probably break reactivity, and helps keeping your code flow clean.

Comment: I understand your confusion. The problem is,  when you `console.log(store.state)`, it puts a reference to the state object in the console, which is later updated. If you use `console.log(JSON.stringify(store.state))` instead, you will see that the role field is in fact blank at the time the routes are selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@neavehni's answer, using Local Storage, may add some unwanted side-effects, such as if multiple people use the the same device. Some better options:

**Navigation Guards**

Using Navigation Guards, add all routes at once, then implement navigation guards to prevent users from navigating to routes that they don't have permission for. (See [documentation on Navigation Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards)). You can use `router.beforeEach` if it is possible to make a unified implementation for all routes, or define the `beforeEnter` guard on each route if each route has very custom requirements. One option to simplify the navigation guard code is to include some information in the `meta` object of each route. This object allows you to define and store any data you wish in association with the route, which can be checked in the `beforeEach` global navigation guard.

**Dynamically Load Routes at Login**

An alternative is to only load a few shared routes in `router.js`. Then, after the user logs in, add the appropriate routes using the router's `addRoutes` method. This method accepts an array of `RouteConfig` objects, so you could use the same route definitions you currently have. See documentation [here](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-addroutes).

Answer (score 0):

The only solution i've found is instead of using vuex store you use the localstorage.